# DNS over 3g/4g Network

Tags: networking

we have over 150 Windows 8 phones and have recently upgraded our cellular connection to have a PAPN (Private APN).  This PAPN connects to our internal network so our users can have access to our internal websites.  Having set this up we have discovered that our supplier does not pass though our network DNS settings and therefore our phones cannot find these websites.  Does anyone know how to get these DNS settings onto our phones or does anyone know if we can use the old fashioned PC "hosts" files on mobiles ??

Comment: Do these phones have a private IP address (e.g. in the 10.0.0.0/8 range), and could you use fully qualified domain names? I know that Bind supports the idea of giving differing answers based on client IP address...